# Passing parameters to stored procedure in data view web part

Tags: 2007, data-view-web-part, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which accepts 2 parameters. The stored proc is executed as

```
EXEC MySP N'Val1, Val2', N'A,B,C'
```

I inserted a Data View Web-Part and tried to get data from stored procedure. But I think I am not able to pass string parameter to SP. Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: without any code, I got no  clue, sorry

Comment: I can still pass numeric parameters and get correct results. But string parameters are not being passed.